# Take Data From Next Row For Which Keyword Has Been Entered

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks similar to this here:

```
id  Continent       Country    State        Area                    Sub Area                   City

77  North America   USA     California  California Desert                                           Ridgecrest
78  North America   USA     California  California Desert                                           Thousand Palms
79  North America   USA     California  California Desert                                           Yucca Valley
80  North America   USA     California  Lake Tahoe Area         Lake Tahoe North Shore              Agate Bay
82  North America   USA     California  California Desert                                           Yucca Valley
83  North America   USA     California  Lake Tahoe Area         Lake Tahoe North Shore              Alpine Meadows
185 North America   USA     California  Lake Tahoe Area                                             Twin Bridges
188 North America   USA     California  Central Coast California    Santa Cruz County               Aptos
189 North America   USA     California  Central Coast California    Santa Cruz County               Ben Lomond
```

I am trying to request data such way that if I search for "California"(State) then only the name of area (next column) and not sub area or cities. Same ways if searched for 'California Desert'(Area) sub Area should show.. (PS at some place I don't have sub areas so it should display sub area where ever applicable if one doesnt have it, move to next which is city)

```
if($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM MasterData WHERE state LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' OR city LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'")){
if($count = $result->num_rows) {

while($rows = $result->fetch_object()) {
echo $rows->city, '</br>';
    }
$result->free();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your construct might have more to it, than meets the eye: Here in Austria, there is a State called Vienna ("Wien"), consisting of the single county Vienna, consisting of the single city Vienna. I think "Washington" also exists as a State, a County (more than once) and a City (more than once)

That said, you could simply do a trickle-down search. This is better done in PHP, but if it must be, you can abuse a UNION:

```
SELECT
  txt
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS level, Country AS txt FROM MasterData WHERE Continent LIKE '$criterion'
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS level, State AS txt FROM MasterData WHERE Country LIKE '$criterion'
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS level, Area AS txt FROM MasterData WHERE State LIKE '$criterion'
  UNION
  SELECT 4 AS level, Subarea AS txt FROM MasterData WHERE Area LIKE '$criterion'
  UNION
  SELECT 5 AS level, City AS txt FROM MasterData WHERE Subarea LIKE '$criterion'
) AS abuseview
ORDER BY level
LIMIT 1
```